# Passing parameters from one page to tabs then tabx

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to pass arguments from a page to tabs page then to just one tab.
So here I passed it from my page to Tabs page :

```
  this.nav.setRoot(TabsNavigationPage, {  nome: displayName });
```

Now in TabsPage I read it

```
 this.displayName = navParams.get('nome');
```

So I edited the html tabs page

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="displayName" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
```

Becouse Im interested only for tab2 for example. So in tabs2 ts I write this :

```
this.displayName = navParams.data.displayName;
```

But it doesn't work.Any suggestion?

Comment: By tabx what do you mean?

Comment: tab2root should be associated with a page/component. You have to access data using navParams in that component.

Comment: @Aravind by tabx I mean tabx where x is a numberm it's just one tab

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by storing it inside the local storage.You can use [**Storage module**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/) for that.

Simple code snippet:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(storage: Storage) {

     storage.ready().then(() => {

       // set as you wish.
       storage.set('nome', 'YourNome');

       // Do this part within Tabx component.Not here :D
       storage.get('nome').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your nome is', val);
       })
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: any feedback for this?